# python threads & sockets

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have a "I just want to understand it" question..
first, I'm using python 2.6.5 on Ubuntu.

So.. threads in python (via thread module) are only "threads", and is just tells the GIL to run code blocks from each "thread" in a certain period of time and so and so.. and there aren't actually real threads here..

So the question is - if I have a blocking socket in one thread, and now I'm sending data and block the thread for like 5 seconds. I expected to block all the program because it is one C command (`sock.send`) that is blocking the thread. But I was surprised to see that the main thread continue to run.
So the question is - how can GIL is able to continue and run the rest of the code after it reaches a blocking command like send? Isn't it have to use real thread in here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Python uses "real" threads, i.e. threads of the underlying platform.  On Linux, it  will use the pthread library (if you are interested, [here is the implementation](http://svn.python.org/view/python/tags/r271/Python/thread_pthread.h?view=markup)).

What is special about Python's threads is the GIL:  A thread can only modify Python data structures if it holds this global lock. Thus, many Python operations cannot make use of multiple processor cores.  A thread with a blocking socket won't hold the GIL though, so it does not affect other threads.

The GIL is often misunderstood, making people believe threads are almost useless in Python.  The only thing the GIL prevents is concurrent execution of "pure" Python code on multiple processor cores.  If you use threads to make a GUI responsive or to run other code during blocking I/O, the GIL won't affect you.  If you use threads to run code in some C extension like NumPy/SciPy concurrently on multiple processor cores, the GIL won't affect you either.

Answer (score 6):

Python [wiki page on GIL](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) mentions that

> Note that potentially blocking or long-running operations, such as ***I/O***, image processing, and NumPy number crunching, happen outside the GIL.

Comment: so if i have x sockets (or other i/o object), and all of them are handled in background (server), does that mean i have 2 real threads: GIL and outside of GIL, so if one socket is blocked, the other will be blocked too?

or i will have x real threads?

(when i say "have x threads" i mean - there could be x real threads in the same time. even if it's for less than a second)

Comment: well, after test - i guess the answer is x real threads. which is now makes things more clear.

Answer (score 5):

GIL (the Global Interpreter Lock) is just a lock, it does not run anything by itself. Rather, the Python interpreter captures and releases that lock as necessary. As a rule, the lock is held when running Python code, but released for calls to lower-level functions (such as `sock.send`). As Python threads are real OS-level threads, threads will not run Python code in parallel, but if one thread invokes a long-running C function, the GIL is released and another Python code thread can run until the first one finishes.

Comment: This is probably the most concise summary of the topic I've seen so far. One nit-pick: the interpreter doesn't release the GIL automatically when it encounters C code, but it is at the discretion of the long-running c-function whether or not the GIL will be released.